# How does live2d work?

Tags: animation, image-processing

[live2d](http://live2d.com/en) can animate a picture and make small movements, just as they show in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrLnF7CQ8Ac%E2%80%8E).

1 Does anyone know how it works?

2 Is there any paper describe the mechanism behind it? I tried google scholar search but find few.

3 Is there any open source work on this field?

Answer (score 2):

1. The fundamental algorithm is like control points in Adobe Illustrator. Control points are like anchors for the image. You can shrink, stretch and bend the image by moving the control points.
2. Unfortunately, NO. Live2D is all developed in the company.
3. For now it is all closed project.